# Возможно отформатировать код без методов списка и строк?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Формат ввода: Одна строка, состоящая из букв `о` (орел) и `р` (решка) — результаты бросков монеты.
Формат вывода: Одно целое число — максимальное число орлов, выпавших подряд

Написал такой код:

```
string = input()
counter = 0
k = 0
spisok = set()
for i in range(len(string) - 1):
    if i <= len(string):
        if string[i] == string[i + 1] == "о":
            counter += 1

        spisok.add(counter)
        if string[i] == "р":
            counter = 0

print(max(spisok) + 1)
```

Как можно решить эту задачу без методов списка и строк?

Comment: а что код делать то должен?

Comment: Формат ввода
Одна строка, состоящая из букв «о» и «р» — результаты бросков.

Формат вывода
Одно целое число — максимальное число орлов, выпавших подряд., где о - орлы

Comment: `print(max(map(len, input().split("р"))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Формат ввода Одна строка, состоящая из букв «о» и «р» — результаты
> бросков. Формат вывода Одно целое число — максимальное число орлов,
> выпавших подряд., где о - орлы

очевидно, что самое простое решение:

```
print(max(map(len, string.split('р'))))
```

или

```
print(len(max(string.split('р'))))
```

но если нельзя использовать работу с массивами и строками, то тогда так:

```
string = input()

counter = 0
counter_max = 0

for l in string + 'р':
    if l == "о":
        counter += 1
    else:
        if counter_max < counter:
            counter_max = counter
        counter = 0

print(counter_max)
```

данный код можно чуть поджать:

```
counter, counter_max = 0, 0

for l in string + 'р':
    counter += 1 if l == "о" else 0
    counter_max = counter if counter_max < counter else counter_max
    counter = counter if l == "о" else 0

print(counter_max)
```

Comment: С массивами можно работать, просто их методы нельзя использовать(. А не могли бы вы написать этот же когда с условиями не в 1 строку, как на 7 строке?

Comment: держите упрощенный код

Answer (score 1):

Списки здесь вообще лишнее.

```
s = input()
max_counter = 0
counter = 0
for c in s:
    if c == "о":
        counter += 1
        max_counter = max(counter, max_counter)
    else:
        counter = 0

print(max_counter)
```

Answer (score 1):

без методов списков и строк, но с регулярным выражением:

```
from re import findall

s = 'ооорроррроорр'
print(len(max(findall('о+', s))))  # 3
```